# Using PowerShell with CSOM to grant permissions to AD security groups

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, active-directory, csom

I have been testing out the provisioning of team sites using Powershell CSOM calls working against an on premise SharePoint 2013 farm. Creating Team Sites this way is very easy. One of the great advantages I have found is  I don't need to RDP to any of the servers on the farm and indeed get "kicked off" if one the other consultants hijacks my admin session!

Now,  I want script the following using CSOM or REST

- Break permission inheritance
- Remove any SharePoint groups
- Granting one or more AD groups the desired "Contribute" or "Design" permissions.

I just wondered if this is possible without needing to be logged on to a farm server and running server side PS script.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  you can accomplish those items without needing the server object model.  You have a few options that are client-side:

- Use CSOM in a console application (does not involve PowerShell).  [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/FP179912.aspx) link has some examples of how to use CSOM, and links to sample code.
- Use CSOM from PowerShell.  [This](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/12/Using-CSOM-in-PowerShell-scripts-with-Office365.html) blog is a great starter.

If you would like help on a particular method, update your answer and I will attempt to do so.

Comment: Thanks very much I will give the second link a go and report back

Comment: I have been advised by the MSDN forum that is currently no support for AD groups in PS/CSOM or PnPComandlets ....Which is why I am back on the server.